# Two questions: should I do client-side or server-side in terms of validation? Also, how would I verify that no textbox is blank/invalid...

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

...with jquery/javascript?  I want to check and make sure that a value has been entered and that it's a number.

First - Is it a best practice to do validation on the client-side, server-side, or both?  Is this something that should be validated twice or is checking on the client-side enough?

Second - If client-side validation is the best way to go about this, how could I do this with javascript/jquery?  I assume that for the button that's clicked, I would assign its `onclientclick` equal to a javascript function.

Comment: You should do both client- and server-side validation, always.

Comment: Client Side for convenience of the user (they can get feedback quickly/as they type) Server side for security (Any user could override client side validation with just a little bit of know how)

Comment: @The Vanilla Thrilla Did the below responses been needful and well addresses your question ?

Comment: @The Vanilla Thrilla Did the below responses been needful and well addresses your question ?

Answer (score 4):

1) Validation should, *at minumum* be done on the server side. **Both** is even better.

2) If you wanted to do easy validation, you would simply attach to either a button click event, or better even, the form submit event.

```
$('form').submit(function()
{
     // Do My Validation

     // return false if invalid, true otherwise
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do both, and you should use [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for the client-side.

Answer (score 2):

Client side validation is purely for convenience of user and server, NOT for data sanitation. Consider the fact that you can open your dev tools and change the JS as you please on the fly - you could completely bypass client side validation. It is, however, good that it doesn't require you to load any more data and allows you to validate before navigating off.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers say, using server-side and client-side together would be best.  Client-side can always be passed by people knowing what they are doing.  Even if someone just turns off Javascript all-together, client-side validation is worthless.

My recommendation is to set up everything on the server, then go back and fix it for the clients.  Javascript and jQuery are the most common items used for validation.  One of the things I use with Javascript is preventing any submit button until after everything checks out, for example:

```
document.getElementById("submitbutton").innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Log In" />';
```

Putting in that after everything checks out with the validation would place the input button in a div with the id of "submitbutton".

An example of some Javascript just to make sure there is input for a box would be this:

```
var textValue = document.getElementById("idOfTextBox").value;
if(textValue == null || textvalue == "")
{
    document.getElementById("errordiv").innerHTML = "Please fill out a value for the text box";
}
```

If this is set for onKeyUp or onBlur for each text box, it can be pretty useful in making sure every box has its input.

Answer (score 0):

There are few client side Validations **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside)**

[image][image]

---

> First - Is it a best practice to do validation on the client-side,
>   server-side, or both? Is this something that should be validated twice
>   or is checking on the client-side enough?

1. `Client Side` - It is always good. provided that the javaScript is not blocked. Client side validation speed up the process. Reduces the execution time.
2. `Server Side` - It's always bother-less. Just need to compromise with the performance.
3. `Both Side` - I can go for `RegularExpressionValidator` and Server side validation.

---

> Second - If client-side validation is the best way to go about this,
>   how could I do this with javascript/jquery? I assume that for the
>   button that's clicked, I would assign its onclientclick equal to a
>   javascript function.

---

> In this Example I will explain how we can prevent the user to type non
>   alphabets in numeric textbox.

### Mark Up

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" AutoComplete="Off" 
             onKeyup="return AlphaNumeric(this);" onchange="return AlphaNumeric(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

---

### Sample JavaScript code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function AlphaNumeric(controlID) {
        document.getElementById(controlID.id).value = 
          NumericValidation(document.getElementById(controlID.id).value);
        return true;
    }

    function NumericValidation(val) {
        var Reg = new RegExp('[^a-zA-Z]+');
        var Result = val.match(Reg);
        if (Result) {
            val = val.replace(Reg, '');
            return val;
        }
        else
            return val;
    }
</script>
```

---